# How to Memcopy and copy back to a char array?

Tags: c++, pointers, memcpy

I would like to copy a variable of 1 byte to relatively larger char array, and copy it back? How can I do that?

```
/* memcpy example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Data {
  unsigned char name[40];
  int age;
};

typedef unsigned char       uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short int  uint16_t;

int main ()
{

    uint8_t myval = 8;
    uint8_t myval_2 = 8;
    Data mypass;

    memcpy(&mypass.name, &myval, sizeof(uint8_t));
    memcpy(&mypass.name+1, &myval_2, sizeof(uint8_t));

    uint8_t* myvalnew = nullptr;
    uint8_t* myvalnew_2 = nullptr;

    memcpy(myvalnew, (uint8_t*)&mypass.name, sizeof(uint8_t));
    memcpy(myvalnew_2, (uint8_t*)&mypass.name+1, sizeof(uint8_t));

    return 0;

}
```

However I am getting errors.

Comment: Can you share with us the error messages?

Comment: Show your errors.

Comment: @Zoldszemesostoros  segmentation fault generally

Comment: Do not take the address of an array type.  You're doing this everywhere and it's wrong.  Furthermore, the last two `memcpy` calls write data to a NULL address.  That's probably where your segfault is coming from.  There is no need to use `memcpy` at all to set a single byte.  Just do `mypass.name[0] = myval; mypass.name[1] = myval_2;`

Comment: `memcpy(myvalnew, (uint8_t*)&mypass.name, sizeof(uint8_t));` copy to a `nullptr`? Ill doom, man, Ill.

Comment: In your second calls to `memcpy`, you're trying to copy the values in `mypass.name` to the address 0 (`nullptr`), which will cause a segfault.

Comment: COuld you please also answer this what would happen if the first element had uint16_t size? and there was a second element in array

Comment: Why is this question tagged C++ if it's pretty much C?

Comment: I edited the question. I changed the question also. answer is irrelevant. I would love to delete since no one wants to answers.

Answer (score 2):

`&mypass.name` creates a pointer to your name array, you want a pointer to the first element of your array, you can use either simply `mypass.name` or `&mypass.name[0]`. `memcpy` is unnecessary here as you can simply assign the elements:

```
mypass.name[0] = myval;
mypass.name[1] = myval_2;
```

Your second set of `memcpy`s will fail as your `myvalnew` pointers are null, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. If you're trying to get the values back you can again just use normal array access:

```
uint8_t myvalnew = mypass.name[0];
uint8_t myvalnew_2 = mypass.name[1];
```

Comment: I tried to initialized this pointer since without nulptr it gave error.

Comment: You need to initialise them to some actual memory, uninitialised and null are both incorrect

Comment: "*you want a pointer to the first element of your array*" - the address of the array and the address of the 1st element are the same address. Passing the array by name without `&` simply *decays* the array into a pointer to the 1st element.

Comment: COuld you please also answer this what would happen if the first element had uint16_t size? and there was a second element in array

Comment: I edited the question could u please check. I would also select you as answer

Comment: Lastly I am using Memcopy because there will be another function which uses shared memeory between processes it is complicated. But could u please check my question again.

Comment: You've completely changed your question which makes most of my answer irrelevant

Comment: COuld you please help me I would like to select an answer? Or we can delete the question and I can ask again